an identity involving sum of stirling number of second kind multiplied by its second parameter $S(n,m) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}S(k, m-1)m^{n-k-1}$
$\displaylines{\text{I am trying to prove by induction}\\ \quad S(n,m) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}S(k, m-1)m^{n-k-1}\\\text{where S is Stirling of the second kind}
 }$
\begin{align}S(n+1,m) &= S(n,m-1) + mS(n,m)\\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}S(k, m-2)(m-1)^{n-k-1} + m\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}S(k, m-1)m^{n-k-1}
\end{align}
$\displaylines{\text{but I couldnt find a way to use $(m-1)^{n-k-1}$ and $m^{n-k-1}$. Thanks in advance}}$

I would encourage you to stare a bit harder at what you've already written. You're so close! Hint: What do you want to show?

First off, we want to do induction on $n$ and $m$ should be fixed.
For $m>n$ the identity obviously holds. If $n=m$ we have $S(n,n)=1$ and on the other hand
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}S(j,n-1)n^{n-j-1}=S(n-1,n-1)n^{n-(n-1)-1}=1.$$
Now onto $n\to n+1:$
Write $S(n+1,m)=mS(n,m)+S(n,m-1)$ which is the recursion of the 2nd Stirling numbers. Then we get \begin{align}
S(n+1,m)&=mS(n,m)+S(n,m-1)\\
&=m\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}S(j,m-1)m^{n-j-1}+S(n,m-1)\\
&=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}S(j,m-1)m^{n-j}+S(n,m-1)m^{n-n}\\
&=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n}S(j,m-1)m^{n-j}.
\end{align}
The tricky part is using the induction hypothesis only partially, i.e. only for the first summand.

facepalm. I am the dumbest person on earth :)

same trick is valid for $S(m+n+1, m) = \sum_{k=0}^{m}k \cdot S(n+k,k)$ and $s(m+n+1) = \sum_{k=0}^{m}(n+k)\cdot  s(n+k,k)$ where $s$ and $S$ are first and second Sterling respectively
